# Type Inference resolution procedure involving throws clause in Java

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, jls

Consider the following article in [JLS §18.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.1.3) - Bounds

Here when we try to identify the set of bounds on the inference variables - we have one of the following situations:

> ...
>
> - throws α: The inference variable α appears in a throws clause.
>
> ...
>
> A bound of the form throws α is purely informational: it directs resolution to
> optimize the instantiation of α so that, if possible, it is not a **checked exception type**.

I think this statement is incorrect:

- this is because ideally the throws clause is mentioned to take care of **checked exceptions** which can happen during the course of execution of the code.
- Then why still the JLS preventing **α** to be a **Checked Exception?**
- Ideally the **inference variable α** must be bounded to be an **exception of Checked type** rather than being an **Unchecked variant**.

**Is my understanding correct here or am I missing something?**

Comment: Do you realise that it is allowed to write unchecked exceptions in a `throws` clause? Your third point is not very reasonable.

Comment: "this statement is incorrect" I'm guessing you mean that you think it shouldn't be designed in this way? The statement is certainly *correct* - the language designers can design it however they want, and `javac`'s behaviour matches this description.

Comment: All I mean is that alpha(α) can be a `Checked Exception` type as well - and JLS should honour that - what seems from the language is that **JLS does not want alpha(α) to be of Checked type.**

Comment: This doesn't say that α _can't_ be a checked exception type, merely that it is not a checked exception type if possible.

Comment: Read the quote again, the language spec does allow alpha to be of a checked exception type. It's just that ***if possible***, it is not so.

Comment: You keep using the word "ideally" - what do you actually mean when you say that? In what respect are your choices ideal, and the choices of the language designers not ideal?

Comment: @Sweeper : okay .. thanks for clarifying - was actually expecting the other statement to be written independently of the first in JLS - coz **if it is of unchecked type - not sure how will it contribute in the Type Inference resolution process.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your interpretation/understanding of this statement is slightly misguided:

> A bound of the form throws α is purely informational: it directs resolution to optimize the instantiation of α so that, if possible, it is not a checked exception type.

That line is referring to the resolution, which, as I understand it, is not about where `throws α` is, but about where `α` is inferred, conceivably the invocation of the method.

Consider this class:

```
static class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass.<RuntimeException>something(0); // same as MyClass.something(1);

        try {
            MyClass.<IOException>something(2);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // checked exception
        }
    }

    /**
     * Will throw IOException if argument is 2, a RuntimeException otherwise
     */
    static <T extends Exception> void something(int a) throws T {
        if (a == 2) {
            throw (T) new IOException(); //of course it's a bad cast
        } else {
            throw (T) new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

After analyzing the two `something` method, focus on the invocation in the `main` method:

The call `MyClass.<IOException>something(0)` expects an IOException. The caller knows it (assume fully documented contract rather than tightly coupled code), and handles the exception.

This already tells you that the variable **can** be a checked exception, contrary to what you think.

On the contrary, the call `MyClass.<RuntimeException>something(0)` expects a runtime exception on similar grounds.

How `α` (`T` in the above example) is inferred allows the compiler to skip forcing the caller to catch/handle the exception (if it's to look at the bound, which it'd otherwise have to)

Now about the "optimization": The type variable being bounded as `extends Exception` can reasonably be expected to resolve to a checked exception. But, if the caller knows that it shall be a runtime exception, it can "inform" the compiler that it's going to be a runtime exception. This is what I did by specifying `RuntimeException` in the type witness (`RuntimeException` is also the resolved type when no type argument is given explicitly).

We can spend days to interpret "optimization", but at least I as a caller did not have to try/catch the invocation, and I still didn't upset the compiler (first invocation).

Answer (score 4):

Consider this example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo(() -> System.out.println("Foo"));
    }

    public static <T extends Exception> void foo(ThrowingRunnable<T> runnable) throws T {
        runnable.run();
    }
}

interface ThrowingRunnable<T extends Exception> {
    void run() throws T;
}
```

During the inference of the type parameter `T` when calling `foo`, there will be a "throws" bound on the type variable `T`, and `T` is inferred to be `RuntimeException`. If not for this bound, `T` would have been inferred as `Exception` because of the `T extends Exception` bound. This would have meant that I needed to do:

```
try {
    foo(() -> System.out.println("Foo"));
catch (Exception e) {
    // This won't be reached!
}
```

I had to handle the exception, even though all I'm doing in the lambda is printing things! That doesn't seem very nice, does it?

The purpose of this bound is so that if there's no reason for the method to throw a checked exception, it doesn't throw a checked exception, so that you don't have to write so many try...catches all over the place. `foo` would *only* throw a checked exception if you do things like:

```
foo(() -> new FileOutputStream("foo"));
```

If the effect of the bound were instead to force `T` to be a checked exception, it wouldn't be very useful at all.

Comment: I find this example much better than @ernest_k’s because it does not enforce the type on the caller’s side, nor does it use unchecked casts.