# Compilation error when calling generic method which throws generic exception

Tags: java, exception, checked-exceptions

I am compiling this class:

```
public class Test {

    // No throws clause here
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doThrow(new SQLException());
    }

    static void doThrow(Exception e) {
        Test.<Exception>doThrow0(e);
        Test.doThrow0(e);
    }


    static <E extends Exception> void doThrow0(Exception e) throws E {
        throw (E) e;
    }
}
```

Why `**Test.<Exception>doThrow0(e);**` this line gives error to specify throws clause  (or enclose it in try-catch )
And `**Test.doThrow0(e);**` this line don't give any error to use throws clause

Comment: Java 17 does not produce an error on the second line, for the record. Probably some weird raw type semantics... What error does Java 21 give you for second line, Slaw?

Comment: @OLEGSHA Never mind. I did something slightly different which was messing things up. I can reproduce on Java 17 and 21.

Comment: The reason it compiles is because `E` is being inferred as `RuntimeException`, which is an _unchecked_ exception. Though I can't currently tell you exactly which part of the JLS mandates/permits this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because type inference *prefers* inferring type parameters that appear in the `throws` clause to unchecked exceptions whenever possible.

From [JLS 18.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.1.3):

> During the inference process, a set of bounds on inference variables is maintained. A bound has one of the following forms:
>
> - ...
> - `throws α`: The inference variable α appears in a `throws` clause.
>
> ...
>
> A bound of the form `throws α` is purely informational: it directs resolution to optimize the instantiation of α so that, if possible, it is not a checked exception type.

In the first attempt to [resolution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.4), this bound is taken into account.

> Otherwise, if the bound set contains `throws αi`, and each proper upper bound of αi is a supertype of `RuntimeException`, then Ti = `RuntimeException`.

In `Test.doThrow0(e)`, there is nothing suggesting that `E` should be a checked exception, so type inference infers it to be `RuntimeException`, an unchecked exception.

If `doThrow0` took an `E` as parameter instead, that establishes a relationship between the type of the argument and the type of the exception `doThrow0` throws. Now `E` would be inferred to be `Exception` in the call `Test.doThrow0(e)`.

In `Test<Exception>doThrow0(e)`, you explicitly specified that `E` should be a checked exception. Type inference doesn't even get involved here.

See also [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71171648/5133585) where you can find examples where this "try not to infer a checked exception" is desirable.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I wanted a reference of JLS documentation regarding my question and you have provided it, I will try to read the resolution part of JLS